# Can I use exiftool with an URL?

Tags: url, exiftool

I'm new at `exiftool` and don't know whether instead of a file, I can put a URL where that file is contained. Can I?

For example:

```
exiftool http://www.edfr.com/images/wert_1.jpg -j /home/damaris/Desktop/metadata.json
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
wget -qO - http://www.edfr.com/images/wert_1.jpg | exiftool -j - > /home/damaris/Desktop/metadata.json
```

Comment: When I try using wget, I get a "command not found" error. However, if use this modified 'piping example' from the official ExifTool documentation, 60+ tags are retuned: `url -s https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNrnd.jpg | exiftool -fast -` .

Comment: What does the `-q` flag do? Doesn't this download the file entirely? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`curl -s http://a.domain.com/bigfile.jpg | exiftool -fast -`

Reference: https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#piping_examples